# Error when reindexing

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex, magento2.3, magento-cron

when I use `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` or `php bin/magento cron:run` I keep getting this error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/[NAME]/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/Write.php on line 35
```

I'm using `php 7.2` and `Magento 2.3`

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I doubled check and my PHP was 7.2 no problem with that. Now the way I was able to fix it was to run this code:

```
[-/public_html]#/usr/local/php72/bin/php-cli bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

instead of:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

to directly execute the command via the php-cli binary.
Same for the other commands such as:

```
bin/magento setup:update
```

seems to be working fine right now. But I don't know the reason I was getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

Make a dummy php file and put  in it. Look for the PHP version and make sure 7.2 is really there. Because this kind of error might occur with incompatible PHP version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought that too but couldn't find the problem there. it was 7.2 in the phpinfo.php file. However I found a solution for the issue which I posted under the question if you want to check it out. Thanks again.